# Catching exit signals in Elixir escript

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'd like to write an escript that reloads its configuration when it receives a HUP signal. I'm on OS X and searching for any new processes in Activity Monitor when I start the escript. When I do, these pop up: inet_gethost (twice), erl_child_setup, and beam.swp. When I send a SIGHUP to erl_child_setup, it crashes with the message of "erl_child_setup closed". When I send it to beam.swp I get a message of "Hangup: 1", but my trapping code is not called.

Here's some example code that illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
defmodule TrapHup do

  def main(args) do
    Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
    main_loop()
  end

  def main_loop() do
    receive do
      { :EXIT, _from, reason } -> 
        IO.puts "Caught exit!"
        IO.inspect reason
        main_loop()
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out this is not possible with just Elixir/Erlang. Apparently it is possible through bash as illustrated in this gist: https://gist.github.com/Djo/bfa9fa75928ce432ec51

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

term_handler() {
  echo "Stopping the server process with PID $PID"
  erl -noshell -name "term@127.0.0.1" -eval "rpc:call('app@127.0.0.1', init, stop, [])" -s init stop
  echo "Stopped"
}

trap 'term_handler' TERM INT

elixir --name app@127.0.0.1 -S mix run --no-halt &
PID=$!

echo "Started the server process with PID $PID"
wait $PID

# remove the trap if the first signal received or 'mix run' stopped for some reason
trap - TERM INT

# return the exit status of the 'mix run'
wait $PID
EXIT_STATUS=$?

exit $EXIT_STATUS
```

Comment: This is very poor quality answer. Links should not be posted as is, please read the rules of this resource. Rather the answer, explaining howtos etc, and related code snippets should be posted here.